# MySql query, counting occurrences of user_id

Tags: php, mysql

My query is:

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT user_id
FROM goals
LEFT JOIN goal_results ON goals.id = goal_results.goal_id
WHERE goals.enabled = 1 AND validation = 'accepted') AS u
```

My results are:

```
| user_id |
| 4 |
| 5 |
| 4 |
| 5 |
| 6 |
```

I need to get the count of each of them like:

4 > 2

5 > 2

6 > 1

I've tried many kind of queries with subqueries or using distinct but I'm lost and I don't reach my goal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this by using [`GROUP BY`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/group-by-functions.html) and [`COUNT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/group-by-functions.html#function_count-distinct). The subquery is not needed.

```
SELECT goal_results.user_id, COUNT(*) qty
FROM goals
LEFT JOIN goal_results ON goals.id = goal_results.goal_id
WHERE goals.enabled = 1 AND goal_results.validation = 'accepted'
GROUP BY goal_results.user_id
```

Comment: Thanks. BTW I've submitted and edit becaused you exchanges the wrong tables in the query but it's ok ! SELECT goal_results.user_id, COUNT(*) qty
FROM goals
LEFT JOIN goal_results ON goals.id = goal_results.goal_id
WHERE goals.enabled = 1 AND goal_results.validation = 'accepted'
GROUP BY goal_results.user_id

Answer (score 1):

Adding group by will do.

```
SELECT u.user_id, count(*) FROM (SELECT user_id
FROM goals
LEFT JOIN goal_results ON goals.id = goal_results.goal_id
WHERE goals.enabled = 1 AND validation = 'accepted') AS u
group by u.user_id
```

Comment: I don't understand why there needs to be a double select here

Comment: I am only good at basic `sql query`. So I didn't dare to modify OP's sql.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to do this with a subquery:

```
SELECT g.user_id, count(*)
FROM goals g LEFT JOIN
     goal_results gr
     ON g.id = gr.goal_id
WHERE g.enabled = 1 AND validation = 'accepted'
GROUP BY g.user_id;
```

My guess, though, is that you really want:

```
SELECT g.user_id, count(gr.goal_id)
FROM goals g LEFT JOIN
     goal_results gr
     ON g.id = gr.goal_id
WHERE g.enabled = 1 AND validation = 'accepted'
GROUP BY g.user_id;
```

This will return `0` for users that have no goals.  The first will return `1` for them.